# Bisecting a line segment with compass only (no ruler)

Tags: geometry

We all know the [construction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bisection) for bisecting a line segment with compass and ruler

[image]

However, I wondered if it's still possible to find the midpoint of the segment **without use of the ruler**, by just constructing circles? You can of course approximate the midpoint, and I see how the problem is equivalent to do a perpendicular projection of a point onto a line with only the compass, but I just don't get the construction. Maybe Thales' theorem, or am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Dammit, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227285/constructing-the-midpoint-of-a-segment-by-compass?rq=1 :)

Comment: The [Mohr-Mascheroni theorem](http://homeweb2.unifr.ch/hungerbu/pub/Mohr/mohr.ps) states that every construction with straightedge and compass can be done with compass only. See also [this page](http://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/compass.shtml) and [that one](http://gogeometry.com/geometry/mascheroni_construction_compass_alone_index.html).