# Mascheroni construction

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

There are two points in one line and a point C which doesn't lie on the line AB. I have to construct a point D such that it is intersection of the line AB and a line which is perpendicular to the line AB and points C and D lies on this perpendicular line.
**I can only use compass and can't link (match) the points.**
It's on the picture.
[image] 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: What is the purpose of the point C?

Comment: Please could you be so kind and remove "on hold" from this question?

Comment: 1) construct mirror image of $C$ with respect to line $AB$, let me call it $C'$. 2) construct mirror image of $A$ with respect to line $CC'$, let me call it $A'$. 3) construct mid point of $A$ and $A'$ using method described in this [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/227300/59379), this will be the point $D$ you seek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is a construction based on the method described in this 
[answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/227300/59379).
At the end is a picture illustrating the configuration/construction.

- Construct two circles (in red) passing through $C$ centered at $A$ and $B$ respectively.
  These two circles intersect at  $C$ and another point $D$.
- Construct a circle (in orange) centered at $C$ passing through $D$.
- Construct a circle (in green) centered at $D$ passing through $C$.
- Start from $D$, following the method of constructing a regular hexagon.
  After two more circles, one find the point $E$ on the orange circle antipodal to $D$.
- Construct a circle (in blue) centered at $E$ passing through $D$.
  This circle intersect the green circle at two points $F$ and $G$.
- Construct two circles (in magenta) through $D$ centered at $F$ and $G$
  respectively.
  They intersect at $D$ and another point $H$.

We have construct totally nine circles. The final point $H$ is lying on 
line $AB$ and line $CH$ is perpendicular to $AB$. i.e. $H$ is the point we seek.

[image: perpendicular line w/o ruler]