# How to construct the circumcenter of a triangle using a compass ONLY.

Tags: geometry, geometric-construction

I just figured out how to find the midpoint between two points using just a compass and no straight edge. A similar approach can be found in this question:

[Constructing the midpoint of a segment by compass](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227285/constructing-the-midpoint-of-a-segment-by-compass)

Now what I am wondering is, **can I find the circumcenter of a scalene triangle using just a compass and no straight edge?**

I am thinking of drawing a perpendicular at C (in the diagram in the link of the answer presented by commenter and has nine likes) and choosing more points as my centres on that line to create a circle with points A and M on it. So in essence, I would be transforming a line (the perpendicular) into a circle, which I can draw using a compass. Yet, I do not really know if and how it helps.

Best of luck!

Comment: http://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/compass.shtml

Comment: It is solved here: http://gogeometry.com/geometry/mascheroni_compass_construct_circumcircle.htm