# How to find a point that divides a triangle into to pieces with equal area

Tags: geometry

For an arbitrary vertex $A$ of an arbitrary triangle, using a compass, how can one find a point $p$ such that the line that goes through $A$ and $p$ divides the triangle into two pieces with the equal area? See the image for clarification.

[image]

Comment: I dunno, I suppose one could try bisecting the side $BC$....

Comment: Bisecting the base is a solid idea. The two sides will have the same perpendicular height, but half the base length.

Comment: Using a compass but no straight edge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bisect the side opposite $A$ and connect that point with $A$. Two triangles will have the same base and height, thus they will have same area. Do you know how to bisect a segment using a compass?

Comment: Bisection is perfect. Done in High school right.

Comment: Bisecting a segment with only a compass is a challenge and it shouldn't be confused with using a compass and straightedge. To bisect a segment with only a compass look at this address: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/227285/constructing-the-midpoint-of-a-segment-by-compass

Comment: @Seyed: it's definitely much easier to do the bisection with a straightedge in addition to compass

Comment: @Vasya, It is true, but I only wrote that because straightedge was not mentioned in the question.