# How to Construct orthogonal circles?

Tags: geometry, recreational-mathematics

Let $C_{1}$ be a circle of unit radius. Let A and B be two points inside $C_{1}$. Now I want to construct another circle $C_{2}$ such that A and B lie on $C_{2}$ and $C_{2}$ is orthogonal to $C_{1}$ at their point of intersection(I want $C_{2}$ in such a way that it intersects $C_{1}$). I tried and failed to find a way to construct such a $C_{2}$.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: need not be..for example construct $C_{1}$ and $C_{2}$ such that they are orthogonal. Now select 2 points on $C_{2}$ whose bisector need not goes through center of $C_{1}$

Comment: My roundabout and inefficient (nay, stupid) way of doing this: apply the fractional-linear map that turns the unit disk into the upper half-plane. Now the problem is easily solved. Of course you have to transform the circle you’ve found back to the original setting.

Comment: Take the inverse of $A$ with respect to the circle $C_1$ to obtain the third point $C$. Now construct the circle containing $A,B,C$.

Comment: @Sigur, very elegant!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, it is answered in Construction 2.1 of this paper: http://comp.uark.edu/~strauss/papers/hypcomp.pdf

Edit upon request: Given two points $A$ and $B$ in the interior of a circle $C_1$, invert $A$ through $C_1$ to $A'$. Now construct the circle through $A$, $B$, and $A'$. Sigur's answer contains a picture of this construction.

The paper discusses general compass-and-straightedge constructions in hyperbolic geometry, where, in particular, geodesics can be modeled as circles perpendicular to the unit circle in $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Nice paper! Thanks.

Comment: While the linked pdf may solve the question, it is not very helpful as an answer since the links may go stale. I know it's twelve pages long, but could you at least vaguely summarize it here?

Comment: @TobiasKienzler As requested.

Comment: Thanks, now the answer deserves the checkmark

Answer (score 5):

Take the inverse of $A$ with respect to the circle $C_1$ ([see here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/146264/31682)) to obtain the third point $C$. Now construct the circle containing $A,B,C$.

[image]